# Create ordinal array with multiple groups

Tags: matlab

I need to categorize a dataset according to different age groups. The categorization depends on whether the Sex is Male or Female. I first subset the data by gender and then use the ordinal function (dataset is from a Matlab example). The following code crashes on the last line when I try to vertically concatenate the subsets:

```
load hospital;
subset_m=hospital(hospital.Sex=='Male',:);
subset_f=hospital(hospital.Sex=='Female',:);

edges_f=[0 20 max(subset_f.Age)];
edges_m=[0 30 max(subset_m.Age)];

labels_m = {'0-19','20+'};
labels_f = {'0-29','30+'};

subset_m.AgeGroup= ordinal(subset_m.Age,labels_m,[],edges_m);
subset_f.AgeGroup = ordinal(subset_f.Age,labels_f,[],edges_f);

vertcat(subset_m,subset_f);
```

Error using dataset/vertcat (line 76)
Could not concatenate the dataset variable 'AgeGroup' using VERTCAT.

Caused by:
    Error using ordinal/vertcat (line 36)
    Ordinal levels and their ordering must be identical.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

It seems that a vital part was missing in the question, here is the answer to the corrected question. You need to use `join` rather than `vertcat`, for example:

```
joinFull = join(subset_f,subset_m,'LeftKeys','LastName','RightKeys','LastName','type','rightouter','mergekeys',true)
```

---

**Solution of original problem**

It seems like you are actually trying to work with the wrong variable. If I change all instances of `hospitalCopy` into `hospital` then everything works fine for me.

Perhaps you copied hospital and edited it, thus losing the validity of the input.
If you really need to have `hospitalCopy` make sure to assign to it directly after `load hospital`.

If this does not help, try using `clear all` before running the code and make sure there is no file called 'hospital' in your current directory.

Comment: Thanks, see edits above. It's not the name of the dataset that is the problem, it's to do with the vertical concatenation of datasets with different types of ordinal categories.

Comment: @SASnewby Now also the new question should be answered!

Comment: thanks, but it creates quite a few unnecessary fields for _right and _left. Is there a way to avoid this?